# Print JSON with "pretty" (indented) format

Tags: json, delphi

If I create a JSON object and print it on the console:

```
LJSONObject:= TJSONObject.Create;
LJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(TJSONString.Create('Hello'), TJSONString.Create('World')));
LJSONObject.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create(TJSONString.Create('Ciao'), TJSONString.Create('Mondo')));
Writeln(LJSONObject.ToString);
```

the result is:

```
{"Hello":"World", "Ciao":"Mondo"}
```

How I can print the result with nicer indentation, like this?

```
{
   "Hello":"World",
   "Ciao":"MOndo"
}
```

Comment: There's no support of `TJSONObject` for pretty print at this time. But with `PrettyPrintJSON` function from [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11797583/960757) you can write something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/QgkYffN3).

Comment: It's not "correct" indentation - indentation doesn't matter for a JSON parser. It's useful for humans reading it though. That makes it "pretty printing" as @David Heffernan calls it in his answer below, or something similar.

Comment: You can also use online tools like http://jsonprettyprint.net if you don't mind copying pasting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TJSONObject` does not support pretty printing.

Other JSON libraries do. For instance [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/), as discussed here: [How do I pretty-print JSON in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511333/how-do-i-pretty-print-json-in-delphi)

Comment: Since Delphi XE5 there is a formatter [`REST.Json.TJson.Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/REST.Json.TJson.Format)

Comment: That's very helpful, and was very hidden AFAIC. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As [Sir Rufo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744164/sir-rufo) pointed out, there is an inbuilt option as of XE5.

```
uses REST.JSON,System.JSON;
...
function PrettyJSON(jsonstring:String):String;
    var jdoc:TJSONObject;
begin
    jdoc:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonstring) as TJSONObject;
    result:=TJSON.Format(jdoc)
end;
```